# Vapor Querying Classes By Distance

Tags: swift, xcode, server, vapor

Let's say I need to query the distance between two classes in vapor.Here is what I mean

```
let distanceBetweenLocations = 5
let CloseLocations = try Locations.query().filter("lat", .distance , .isLessThan , 4)
```

Something like that

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense... Please, rewrite it, and we can help you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you understand that your question is logically wrong.

It is obvious that you will have to do some kind of calculation to actually get the distance.

I suggest creating extension with func over your model which will calculate distance between coordinates, and then use if in filter func....

Something like this perhaps:

```
extension Location{
  func distance(lat: Double, lon: Double) -> Double {

      let R = 6371.0
      let dLat = (lat - localLat) * 3.14 / 180
      let dLon = (lon - localLon) * 3.14 / 180
      let latRad1 = localLat * 3.14 / 180
      let latRad2 = lat * 3.14 / 180

      let a1 = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2)
      let a2 = sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2) * cos(latRad1) * cos(latRad2)

      let a = a1 + a2
      let c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a))
      return R * c
  }
}
```

I am trying not to be rude but 
I hope that you were just lazy to ask correctly, in case you were not, see [this](https://github.com/syky27/LostSocks-api/) test project read it all try to understand and when you do, you will know how to achieve what you need.